# How to push changes on master branch and tag

Tags: git, github

I have a repo on github and 1 relative tag of it "V1.0.0" now let's say that I do same changes on my code but not enough for upgrade it to another version, but still I have to push the changes on the master and on the tag V1.0.0.

When I tried to do that I before pushed the changes to the master branch and without problem it worked, but then when i tried to push it on the tag 1.0.0 it say me that is`Every thing up to date` and i cannot push the changes even on the tag.

I tried to push the changes on the tag with the following command

```
git push origin v1.0.0
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Git tags are designed to be immutable. Just like you shouldn't rewrite shared commits, you shouldn't rewrite shared tags. The reason that versions are often given as X.Y.Z is so that you *can* release minor versions. That's what they're for. Just release `v1.0.1` and be done with it.

Comment: Thanks a lots for the explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like Chris said, using a minor version like V1.0.1 might be a better approach. However if you insist to do this. Here are the steps:

Move your tag to the newer commit:

```
$ git tag -f -a V1.0.0
```

Delete remote tags:

```
$ git push origin :refs/tags/V1.0.0
```

Push tag to remote repo

```
$ git push origin --tags
```

Comment: Thanks a lots, I probably use the v1.0.1 :)